# Desplegar operación en orden infijo en python

Tags: python

Verán, de antemano gracias por la ayuda.
Necesito desplegar una operación con signos básicos de operación como por ejemplo: '5*4-5/6-3+2'
Ya tengo algo hecho pero, mi profesora requiere que se haga con cualquier operación y he estado pensando durante días como hacerlo de la manera más fácil (si es que hay una); pues mi código esta hecho un desastre pero si logré momentaneamente que se desplegara.

```
def multiPrimero():
 mulI = lista.index('*')
 first = (lista[mulI-1]) * (lista[mulI + 1])
 lista.pop(mulI-1)
 mulI = lista.index('*')
 lista.pop(mulI + 1)
 mulI = lista.index('*')
 lista.insert(mulI, first)
 mulI = lista.index('*')
 lista.pop(mulI)

 listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for i,elem in enumerate(lista)])
 print(listToStr)

 divI = lista.index('/')
 first = (lista[divI-1]) / (lista[divI + 1])
 lista.pop(divI-1)
 divI = lista.index('/')
 lista.pop(divI + 1)
 divI = lista.index('/')
 lista.insert(divI, first)
 divI = lista.index('/')
 lista.pop(divI)

listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for i,elem in enumerate(lista)])
print(listToStr)

sumI = lista.index('+')

resI = lista.index('-')

if sumI < resI:
    sumI = lista.index('+')
    first = (lista[sumI-1]) + (lista[sumI + 1])
    lista.pop(sumI-1)
    sumI = lista.index('+')
    lista.pop(sumI + 1)
    sumI = lista.index('+')
    lista.insert(sumI, first)
    sumI = lista.index('+')
    lista.pop(sumI)

    listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for i,elem in enumerate(lista)])
    print(listToStr)   
    
    sumI = lista.index('+')
    first = (lista[sumI-1]) + (lista[sumI+1])
    lista.pop(sumI-1)
    sumI = lista.index('+')
    lista.pop(sumI + 1)
    sumI = lista.index('+')
    lista.insert(sumI, first)
    sumI = lista.index('+')
    lista.pop(sumI)
    
    listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for i,elem in enumerate(lista)])
    print(listToStr)
    
    resI = lista.index('-')
    first = (lista[resI-1]) - (lista[resI + 1])
    lista.pop(resI-1)
    resI = lista.index('-')
    lista.pop(resI + 1)
    resI = lista.index('-')
    lista.insert(resI, first)
    resI = lista.index('-')
    lista.pop(resI)
    
    listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for i,elem in enumerate(lista)])
    print(listToStr)
    
    sumI = lista.index('+')
    first = (lista[sumI-1]) + (lista[sumI + 1])
    lista.clear()
    lista.append(first)

    listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for i,elem in enumerate(lista)])
    print(listToStr)
    
else:
    resI = lista.index('-')
    first = (lista[resI-1]) - (lista[resI + 1])
    lista.pop(resI-1)
    resI = lista.index('-')
    lista.pop(resI + 1)
    resI = lista.index('-')
    lista.insert(resI, first)
    resI = lista.index('-')
    lista.pop(resI)
    
    listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for i,elem in enumerate(lista)])
    print(listToStr)
    
    sumI = lista.index('+')
    first = (lista[sumI-1]) + (lista[sumI + 1])
    lista.clear()
    lista.append(first)
    
    listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for i,elem in enumerate(lista)])
    print(listToStr)
```

Ese es un ejemplo, el despliegue debe de seguir la jerarquía de signos.

Mi string en este caso:

```
string = '4/2-2+4*2'
```

Mi output:

```
4 / 2 - 2 + 4 * 2
2.0 - 2 + 4 * 2
2.0 - 2 + 8
2.0 - 10
-8.0
```

Así es como se debe de desplegar el resultado pero hay varias inconsistencias, tienen una idea sobre alguna librería, alguna forma de optimizar para que no haya errores cuando por ejemplo hay signos repetidos o algo parecido, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Se que mi código es un desastre pero empezó como un boceto y termine haciendo cualquier cosa para obtener el resultado.
PD: ignoren la indentación. Gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por solicitud del bot: Necesito desplegar una operación paso por paso en notación infija

Comment: "Necesito desplegar ...." no es una pregunta, sino una petición.

Answer (score 0):

Para estos casos se manejan dos stacks: uno de valores y otro de operaciones.

Recorres la expresión colocando valores en su stack. Cuando te encuentras con un operador, lo comparas con el operador en el stack de operaciones. Si la nueva operación es de mayor prioridad que aquella en el stack, la guardas en el stack.

Si la nueva operación es de menor o igual prioridad, la evaluas sacando los dos valores del stack de valores.

Queda así:

```
expresion = '8/2-3+4*5'
valores = []
operaciones = []
prioridad = {'+': 0, '-': 0, '/':1, '*':1, ' ':-1}

for x in expresion + ' ':
    if x.isdigit():
        valores.append(int(x))
    else:
        while operaciones and prioridad[operaciones[-1]] >= prioridad[x]:
            b = valores.pop()
            a = valores.pop()
            op = operaciones.pop()
            if op == "*":
                valores.append(a * b)
            elif op == '/':
                valores.append(a / b)
            elif op == '+':
                valores.append(a + b)
            elif op == '-':
                valores.append(a - b)
        operaciones.append(x)

    print(valores, operaciones)
```

produce:

```
[8] []
[8] ['/']
[8, 2] ['/']
[4.0] ['-']
[4.0, 3] ['-']
[1.0] ['+']
[1.0, 4] ['+']
[1.0, 4] ['+', '*']
[1.0, 4, 5] ['+', '*']
[21.0] [' ']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Versión compacta

Es una lata tener que hacer tantos `if` para determinar que operación realizar finalmente.

Por cada operador binario aritmético, Python ofrece una implementación funcional alternativa. Por ejemplo, la suma la puedes realizar con

```
a + b
```

o su equivalente

```
operator.add(a, b)
```

Nos conviene crear un diccionario indexado por el símbolo de la operación y que me retorne la función correspondiente. Así elimino la necesidad de tanto `if`:

```
import operator

expresion = '8/2-3+4*5'
valores = []
operaciones = []
prioridad = {'+': 0, '-': 0, '/':1, '*':1, ' ':-1}
operadores = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.truediv}
for x in expresion + ' ':
    if x.isdigit():
        valores.append(int(x))
    else:
        while operaciones and prioridad[operaciones[-1]] >= prioridad[x]:
            b = valores.pop()
            a = valores.pop()
            op = operaciones.pop()
            valores.append(operadores[op](a, b))
        operaciones.append(x)

    print(valores, operaciones)
```

La misma facilidad está disponibles para operadores lógicos, de comparación, inclusión, etc. Más información en https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/operator.html

Comment: Muchísimas gracias
Me solucionaste la vida.